# How do I consolidate multiple virtual disks attached to a VM guest?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I adopted a quirky environment.  One of my DFS servers is a Windows Server 2003 Standard R2 server with:

- (1) virtual drive for OS partition (C)
- (1) virtual drive for temporary storage (F)
- (5) virtual drives for file storage (E)

The (5) virtual drives are set up as a dynamic disk.  I want to consolidate them into (1) virtual disk.

I have considered using `dd_rescue` by adding another virtual disk in the size that I need, then doing a bit-by-bit copy of my E drive, but I'm concerned it may have adverse effects on my DFS cache if the new drive doesn't take the E drive letter upon boot-up after I move the partitions.  I'm also not sure if `dd_rescue` has any issues working with dynamic disks.

I've also considered doing a V-to-V, but that process could take a while to complete with 1.8TB of data total.

Is there a way I can consolidate the (5) virtual drives without the risk of corrupting my DFS?  If so, how do I consolidate multiple virtual disks attached to a VM guest?  (I'm running VMware vCenter/vSphere ESXi 5.5)

Comment: See this article for how to preseed an DFS-R folder for adding a new member.  Basically just follow the same procedure to copy the folder to the new drive, then delete, and re-create your DFS config on that system.

Comment: I would love to read the article, but it's not attached.

Comment: Ack, sorry about that, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495044.aspx also http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/09/07/replacing-dfsr-member-hardware-or-os-part-2-pre-seeding.aspx

Comment: There's no need to consolidate the disks. Is there another reason for wanting to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, with dynamic disks you've essentially stuck the drives together as far as Windows is concerned. There's no way that I know of to "combine" VMDK disks (at least, for separate disks ...ESXi does split disks for snapshots/independent disks on its own) - only expand/compact.

I'd imagine it was like this because of the 512 GB volume limit in VMFS3. VMFS5 goes up to 2 TB, so your best bet would be to create a new volume, attach it, then copy all the data over. If you're using DFS, that metadata carries over if you use a tool like `robocopy` to do the copying.